# KeyError Using Google DataLab on datetime64 dtype

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I am using Googles datalab to query BigQuery and use that data for an RNN. I am trying to convert the majority of the data to a numeric format but I am receiving a KeyError for the "Date" column. If I leave it as a string my code works but I need the date field to remain a datetime data type for the RNN. My code and the error are posted below.

```
import datalab.bigquery as bq
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import shutil

%%javascript
$.getScript('https://kmahelona.github.io/ipython_notebook_goodies/ipython_notebook_toc.js')

%%sql --m log_data
SELECT resource, place_id, CAST(end_time AS TIMESTAMP) AS Date, device, device_os, device_os_version, CAST(latency AS FLOAT) AS Latency,
CAST(megacycles AS FLOAT) AS Megacycles, method, CAST(response_size AS FLOAT) AS Response_Size, CAST(cost AS FLOAT) AS Cost, status,
device_brand, device_family, browser_version, app, ua_parse
FROM [project:app_logs_data] 
WHERE DATE(CAST(end_time AS DATE)) >='2018-03-09' AND DATE(CAST(end_time AS DATE)) <='2018-03-10'
GROUP BY resource, place_id, Date, device, device_os, device_os_version, Latency, Megacycles, method,
        Response_size, Cost, status, device_brand, device_family, browser_version, app, ua_parse

logs = bq.Query(log_data).to_dataframe()
logs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(logs['Date'])
logs['resource'].apply(str)

logs.dtypes
resource                     object
place_id                     object
Date                 datetime64[ns]
device                       object
device_os                    object
device_os_version            object
Latency                     float64
Megacycles                  float64
method                       object
Response_Size               float64
Cost                        float64
status                       object
device_brand                 object
device_family                object
browser_version              object
app                          object
ua_parse                     object
dtype: object

def handle_non_numerical_data(logs):
    columns = logs.columns.values

    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}
        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]
        if logs[column].dtype != np.int64 and \
                logs[column].dtype != np.float64 and logs[column].dtype != np.datetime64:
            column_contents = logs[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements = set(column_contents)
            x = 0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                    x+=1
            logs[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, logs[column]))
    return logs

logs = handle_non_numerical_data(logs)


KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-27437e47a873> in <module>()
     17     return logs
     18 
---> 19 logs = handle_non_numerical_data(logs)

<ipython-input-8-27437e47a873> in handle_non_numerical_data(logs)
     14                     text_digit_vals[unique] = x
     15                     x+=1
---> 16             logs[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, logs[column]))
     17     return logs
     18 

<ipython-input-8-27437e47a873> in convert_to_int(val)
      5         text_digit_vals = {}
      6         def convert_to_int(val):
----> 7             return text_digit_vals[val]
      8         if logs[column].dtype != np.int64 and                 logs[column].dtype != np.float64 and logs[column].dtype != np.datetime64:
      9             column_contents = logs[column].values.tolist()

KeyError: Timestamp('2018-03-09 00:00:00')
```

Comment: The `datalab.*` is a deprecated library, you should switch to using `google.datalab.*`, and the `%%bq` instead of `%%sql`. See if that has already been fixed in the new library.

Comment: @yelsayed Thanks for the headsup. I am following a course on Udemy but using my own data set. These were the library's they were using. I will load these library's and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @yelsayed This worked great! It even speed up the query to dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, moved to an answer so this can be marked resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datalab.*` is a deprecated library, you should switch to using `google.datalab.*`, and the `%%bq` instead of `%%sql`. See if that has already been fixed in the new library.